# Mongoose referencing models in other models

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, mongoose, require

I am working on an express/node app, using mongodb and mongoose to model users, players, teams, etc.  Between these models I am using references with ObjectIDs, so between players and teams there is a connector model RosterSpot which holds a team_id and player_id, both with the Schema type of ObjectID.

Anyways, I am running into problems trying to reference RosterSpots inside of the Team and Player models.  I would like to have a method for Players that grabs all their teams, and vice versa for Teams.  First, given this code in roster_spot.js

```
// Synchronously load model dependecies, so foreign model calls can be made
var fs = require('fs');
var models_path = __dirname;
fs.readdirSync(models_path).forEach(function (file) {
  if (~file.indexOf('.js')) require(models_path + '/' + file);
})

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
var Team = mongoose.model('Team');
var Player = mongoose.model('Player');

var RosterSpotSchema = new Schema({
    team_id: {type: ObjectId, required: true},
    player_id: {type: ObjectId, required: true}
});

....

RosterSpotSchema.statics.getTeamsForPlayer = function(player_id, callback) {
    this.getTeamIdsForPlayer(player_id, function(ids){
        Team.find({ _id: { $in: ids } }, function(err, teams){
            callback(teams);
        });
    });
};
...
```

this works perfectly fine, as this RosterSpot model calls the Team.find() and Player.find() methods without a problem.

The problem comes when I try to make that call in the Player or Team model in the following method in player.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RosterSpot = mongoose.model('RosterSpot');
var PlayerSchema = new Schema({...});

...

 PlayerSchema.methods.getTeams = function (callback) {
    RosterSpot.getTeamsForPlayer(this._id, function(teams){
        callback(teams);
    })
 };
```

When I have the `var RosterSpot = mongoose.model('RosterSpot');` in there, it throws a "MissingSchemaError: Schema has not been registered for 'RosterSpot'."
I've tried loading in the models via `require` and async stuff but nothing is working.

The crazy thing is, though, that I've been able to call these sorts of methods for users and players, using the connector model Family and that all works fine.  I don't even have to initialize a variable for Family in users.js, which is weird but it works...

I have thought that maybe it is my testing environment that might mess with loading files, but when I start the server it also throws that error.  Would be helpful to know if this is even possible, and any insight to this problem would be much appreciated.